# Angular 1.5 component/require dependency injection of $log

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, components

I have been trying to inject $log in to a component created by a require statement for some client Angular.

```
var App = require('./app/containers/App');
var Header = require('./app/components/Header');
require('angular-ui-router');
var routesConfig = require('./routes');

import './index.css';
angular
  .module('app', ['ui.router'])
  .config(routesConfig)
  .controller(App.App, ['$log'])
  .service('todoService', todos.TodoService)   
  .component('app', App)
  .component('headerComponent', Header);
```

The code for header is

```
module.exports = {
  template: require('./Header.html'),
  controller: Header,
  bindings: {
    todos: '='
  }
};

/** @ngInject */
function Header(todoService) {
  this.todoService = todoService;
}

Header.prototype = {
  handleSave: function (text) {
    if (text.length !== 0) {
      this.todos = this.todoService.addTodo(text, this.todos);
    }
  }
};
```

~
The code for App is

```
module.exports = {
  template: require('./App.html'),
  controller: App
};

function App($log) {

  this.log = $log;
  $log.error('Hello from App');
}
```

I can inject $log as dependency for App as I have access to the controller.  But attempting the same task for Header is difficult,because Header is created by require which does not seem to allow access to the controller function.

What I like to know is there a way round this?
I am trying to find a way of logging information from any possible javascript function in header.js.

I have seen any alternatives other than using $log to log information in a client side application

My solution so far has been to say in code written in the require block.

```
  var ing = angular.injector(['ng']);
  this.$log = ing.get('$log');

  this.$log.error('I am a message');
```

I think this is the wrong way of doing things, it gives me what I want, but I expect it will break at some point.  I find having access to $log is useful for debugging only.  Its not sort of thing I need for any production code.

Comment: The use of `angular.injector` is a common mistake, because it doesn't work as it is expected to work and indicates some design problem. The question doesn't contain `App` and `Header`, while they are relevant, and the thing you're trying to do should be done there.

Comment: looks like you are using `.controller(App.App, ['$log'])` in a wrong way. Try this one: `.controller('App', ['$log', App.App])`

Comment: In components, services are injectable in the construction function of the component's controller. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).

Comment: Additionally you may specify `$inject` for your `App.App`. This would look like this: `App.App.$inject = ['$log'];` inside `./app/containers/App` file

Comment: Show the code for `Header`. It is hard to help you with that code if we can't see it.

Comment: I accept that the use of angular.injector is wrong, I was looking for a better way hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

All I was trying to do was to get access to the $log angular wrapper.  Turns out all I had to do was add $log to the argument list.

```
function Header(todoService,$log) {
  $log.log('I am a log message');
  this.todoService = todoService;
}
```

I am bit of a Angular 1.5 newbie and I had assume that you had to inject the $log to get the right response.  Just declare it seems to be a bit of a kop out.